# An equation in $\mathbb Z[x]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $$p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+……+a_2x^2+a_0;\space\space (a_1=0)$$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$; let $\mathcal S$ the set of all such polynomials.

It is considered the equation

$$p(13)+p(13^2)+p(13^3)+……+p(13^{12})=12^{13};\space\space p\in \mathcal S \qquad (*) $$

Prove that the equation (*) has infinitely many solutions but if we add the condition 
$p(13)=p’(13)$,where $p'$ is the derivative of $p$, then there is no solution at all.

Comment: Working a bit with that, I found that equation (*) has no solutions in $S$, since necessarily $\sum_{j=1}^{13} p(13^j)$ must be divisible by $13$, while $12^{13}$ is not. Is it possible that there is any typo in your question?

Comment: @Crostul: I see now, there is a typo. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation can be written as
$$ 12a_0 + \big(\sum_{i=1}^{12}(13^i)^2\big)a_2 + \big(\sum_{i=1}^{12}(13^i)^3\big)a_3 + \ldots + \big(\sum_{i=1}^{12}(13^i)^n\big)a_n = 12^{13}.  $$

Note that all coefficients are multiples of $12$ (since $13$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $12$).  Hence we can divide by $12$ and still have integer coefficients, thus getting
$$ a_0 + \frac{\big(\sum_{i=1}^{12}(13^i)^2\big)}{12}a_2 + \frac{\big(\sum_{i=1}^{12}(13^i)^3\big)}{12}a_3 + \ldots + \frac{\big(\sum_{i=1}^{12}(13^i)^n\big)}{12}a_n = 12^{12}.  $$
Since the coefficient in front of $a_0$ is $1$, this equation has infinitely many integer solutions.  Indeed, just choose $a_2, \ldots, a_n$ arbitrarily, and a unique choice for $a_0$ will arise.  Note, though, that $a_0$ will never be a multiple of $13$, since $12^{12}$ is not, while all other terms are.

Now, $p(13)=p'(13)$ can be written as
$$ a_0 + (13^2-2\cdot 13)a_2 + (13^3-3\cdot 13^2)a_3 + \ldots + (13^n - n\cdot 13^{n-1})a_n = 0.$$

This would imply that $13$ divides $a_0$, which is impossible by the above.

Comment: Salut Pierre! Can you explain me, please, why "all coefficients are multiples of 12"? What I can see is that $a_2+a_3+...+a_n$ is multiple of $12$. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito What I mean is that, for all $k$, the number $\sum_{i=1}^{12}(13^i)^k$ is a multiple of $12$.  To see it, just see that, modulo $12$, this becomes $\sum_{i=1}^{12}(1^i)^k$, which is zero.

Comment: O.K. I understood all the coefficients $a_k$ of the polynomial. I have solved otherwise, however it was essentially the same thing. I'll put the green color as the better answer. Thanks you.